# How do I create a mutation that pushes to an array rather than replacing it?

Tags: graphql

I've been playing with GraphQL recently, and am currently learning about mutations. I'm a bit confused with something. I have a model `Post` with relation `Comments`. I have a mutation that looks like this:

```graph-ql
mutation addCommentToPost {
  updatePost(
    id: "POST-1",
    comments: [{
      body: "Hello!"
    }]
  ) {
    id,
    comments {
      id,
      body
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is, whenever I run this, it seems to remove all the comments and sets the comments to only the one I just added. To be more specific, how do I write a mutation that *pushes* to the `comments` array rather than replacing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a mutation called `updatePosts`, which I assume (based on the name) simply updates a post by replacing the fields that are passed. If you want to use the `updatePosts` mutation to add a comment, you will first have to query for the post to get the current list of comments, add your comment to the end, and then call `updateComment` with the entire list of comments (including the one that you just added to the end).

However, this isn't really a good solution, especially if the list of comments is potentially very long. If you have the ability to change the GraphQL **server**, you should create a new mutation on the server with a signature like `addComment(postId: ID, comment: CommentInput)`. In the resolve function for that mutation, simply add the comment that is passed to the end of the list of current comments.

```
// resolver for addComment:
addComment(root, args) {
  // validate inputs here ...

  const post = db.getPost(args.postId);
  post.comments.append(args.comment);
  db.writePost(post.id, post);
}
```

`db.getPost` and `db.writePost` are functions you have to define yourself to retrieve/write a post from/to wherever you store it.

It's important to note that unlike a SQL or Mongo query, a GraphQL mutation itself doesn't have any meaning without the resolve functions. What the mutation does is defined **entirely** inside its resolve function. Mutation names and arguments only gain meaning together with the resolve function. It's up to you (or the GraphQL server developers in your company) to write the resolve functions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Although the other answer was more directed to my exact situation (using Graphcool), this one dives into deeper into the solution so I've marked it correct.

Answer (score 1):

The way this situation is currently solved in the [Graphcool API](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/overview-heshoov3ai/) is to use a create mutation for the `Comment` that links to the `Post`. This is called a [nested connect mutation](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/simple-api/nested-connect-mutations-tu9ohwa1ui/).

This is how it would look like:

```
mutation {
  createComment(
    text: "Hello!"
    postId: "POST-1"
  ) {
    id
    text
    post {
      comments {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In the future, other nested arguments like `comments_set` or `comments_push` could be introduced, then pushing would be possible like this:

```
mutation addCommentToPost {
  updatePost(
    id: "POST-1",
    comments_push: [{
      body: "Hello!"
    }]
  ) {
    id,
    comments {
      id,
      body
    }
  }
}
```

Disclosure: I work at Graphcool.

Comment: any idea when `comments_push` might be introduced?

Answer (score -2):

You can use those code as an example for mutation.

```
module.exports = (refs) => ({
  type: refs.commentType,
  args: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    body: {
      type: GraphQLString
    }
  },
  resolve: (parent, args, root) => {
    return createUser(args);
  }
});
```